# Publishing without a target database?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I'm just beginning to investigate whether SSDT will work for us, in managing our database deployments. I've barely scratched the surface, but there's something that's pretty much stopped me from proceeding.

When I publish a database project, it insists on my providing it with a target database, even if all I want to do is to generate a script.  I don't understand this.

What I want is to have the old version of the database defined in version control, and the new version of the database defined in version control, and to generate a script that will update the old version to the new, and then to apply that script to a number of databases in different environments, from testing, to staging, to the various production servers.

If the process of generating the script depends on the target database, then the script we run in production might be different than the one we ran in testing or staging, with the result that we're really running an untested script on production.

And that we simply cannot allow.

So, given that I have two different versions of the same database project, how can I generate an update script that will modify a database that has the schema of the old version to having the schema of the new?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a script, you don't have to publish, it is enough if you build the project. The sql file should be created in the bin folder.

To update the schema in SSDT project on a database, you can either one of the below,

- publish (setting target database)
- use SqlPackage and .dacpac created by build
- use the sql script created by build

Comment: Do those alternative methods provide hooks for pre- and post-deploy scripts?

Comment: I am not sure about the sql script, but in other methods pre & post deployment scripts will work fine.

Comment: Just noticed, pre & post deployment scripts are included in sql script as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a target database in order to publish. The whole point of using a tool such as SSDT or Red-Gate's SQL Source Control is to make your target database look like your project. The script generated is not the issue in this case, but the fact that your environments are all different and you want to make them the same.

If you want to see the script before you run it (usually a good idea, especially for production), run the "Publish" command but choose to Generate a Script instead of making the changes directly. You can then review the script before running it in production. I'd recommend this anyway to see what will change in Production as a result of what you have in your project. You might even choose to do a schema compare to visually compare the differences and verify that you won't accidentally lose something in production because it's not in the project.

Ideally, take a backup of production, restore it, and run your project against that database to see what happens. Once your environments are more in sync, the scripts used in lower environments should mirror those run against production (barring environment-specific variables and such).

You can definitely generate dacpacs and compare between those, but you really want to generate scripts, look at them, and get comfortable with seeing how SSDT will generate a script to bring your production database in line with your project. Once it's gone through that process once, the changes afterwards will likely be much smaller and confined to the changes you want.

The bigger issue to address here is why your lower environments could be that different from production. As long as they're out of sync and you have people making changes that aren't in source control, you run the risk of having inconsistent releases because someone forgot to check in a changed/new object. You might also need to address issues arising from people making ad-hoc changes to production without them being checked in to your source control. Those sorts of changes are easy to miss if people are just trying to fix something and forget to get those fixes back to source control.

Comment: The whole approach seems dangerously ad-hoc, to me.  I don't want to generate a script that I will "examine", I want to generate a script that I will run, unchanged, against multiple environments. First, against our QA environment, then against a staging environment that is a copy of a production environment, then against multiple production environments.  Running untested scripts strikes me as a recipe for disaster.

Comment: That's not quite how these work, though. The point of SSC and SSDT is to make the target look like your project. You want consistency. Admittedly, you also want to avoid huge table rebuilds, but that shouldn't be the case if your environments are correctly set up. Gen the scripts a couple of times to see what the projects will do. I think it will give you a bit more comfort. For what it's worth, I typically gen scripts/diff reports before each release just so I know what's likely to change, but for our Dev/QA environments often just let it run after a quick review.

Comment: Jeff, you may want to read a bit more about the way SSDT and SSC work to get some behind the scenes info. Jamie Thomson has some excellent writing on SSDT/DataDude/DB Projects here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/   I've blogged about it here: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/10/all-ssdt-articles.html  Red-Gate has a lot of stuff about SQL Source Control on their site/blogs.  The scripts aren't as ad-hoc as you think and you can always gen a script to run against all, but the main goal is probably consistency.

Comment: An SSDT project contains a model of the database. Every version of the project will contain a different version of the model. Given any two versions, I should be able to generate a script that will update one to the other, and I should be able to run that script against any database that matches the version.

Comment: That is true, but ... if the database has any differences at all the script could fail. Say someone decided to do an emergency fix to some environment and never committed that change - that would be a difference in that one environment. If you're confident that this will never happen, you can generate one script and go with it. If you ever have those environments get slightly out of sync, you could have other problems. I'm not saying that you _can't_ gen up a single script and use it, just that this is not quite the way DBs were set to be published in SSDT.

Comment: I'd be confident that it would never happen only if there were measures in place to ensure that it didn't, and if there were additional measures in place to detect and alert when it happened anyway. But in my mind, that sort of thing should be a standard part of the normal system monitoring necessary to keep any non-trivial system functioning. If it's possible for anyone to make unreported changes to your databases, you have serious problems.

Comment: I'll tend to agree with that, though it happens more often in Dev or even Local environments. I still recommend reading up on SSDT a little bit to see how others typically use it. I review the Prod scripts but will admit to giving a more cursory look at Dev/QA/Staging just to see _what_ will change rather than exactly how. Of course, we also tend to leap-frog our releases a bit so a release could be fast-tracked ahead of the others resulting in some bits hitting Prod before earlier bits. Letting SSDT just make Prod "right" has saved a lot of my sanity. :)

Comment: We've been questioning whether SSDT is solving the right problem, for our work flow. Or perhaps it's better to say that we're questioning whether SSDT is the right tool for our problem.  Something like Fluent Migrator seems like it might be a better fit.

Comment: It is possible that SSDT isn't the right fit for you. We're comfortable letting the scripts change the DB to match what we expect. If that's not what you need/want, another product might be better. There's always something like DBDeploy as well - save all the scripts and run them. We have a little too much uncertainty in what will go and when to try to manage a bunch of scripts like that.